# English word for "kör olası"

Tags: translation

The word "kör olası" in Turkish is kind of similar in usage to the word "damned" in English but with a different meaning. It literally means "my it be blinded". So, for instance,

> I jabbed a finger at his *kör olası* eye

literally means

> I jabbed a finger at his *may it be blinded* eye.

Is there a word for this in English?

Comment: I don't understand what you're after here, The exact idiom doesn't translate, obviously (it probably wouldn't be an *idiom* if it did). What's wrong with ***damned*** (more rarely, ***damnable***)? That effectively means *may it be damned*, where *to be damned* means ***to be condemned by God to suffer eternal punishment in hell***. Eternal punishment for an *eye* is likely to include "blinding" it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes but "damned" does not specifically mean "may the eye be blinded".

Comment: No, but [*Damn your eyes!*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22damn+your+eyes%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=YukvVaybDtjiasHygagE) does (we always use the plural for our version).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ok thanks but I'm translating a sentence from Turkish...so I cannot use the plural form when it's singular in the original sentence...

Comment: It is a cultural expression so the equivalent would be "damn" in Western cultures. *I jabbed a finger at his damn eye!*  [*Bloody* can be used in UK also]

Comment: @ermanen: I'd have thought that strictly speaking it should be ***damned***. You wouldn't always enunciate the /d/ in, say, *"Call off your damn dog!"*. But when the following noun starts with a vowel it would sound odd to me not to (I wouldn't know whether to enunciate the /n/ or not! :)

Comment: Is this a general pejorative in Turkish? Could you also say, “He hit me on the wrist with that _kör olası_ walking stick of his”? Or is it something that can only be applied to eyes and expresses a literal desire for the eye in question to become blind?

Comment: The "may it be blinded" part sounds like a curse so I wonder if you could use this common replacement: "I jabbed a finger at his cursed eye!"  FWIW, in that usage of the word "cursed", I always hear it pronounced "curs-ed".

Comment: My first idea was _bloody_, as someone can refer a wish of a physical injury, using it, and it may be used more widely, than the one which is appealing to eyes only. The etymology of the _bloody_ curse seems to be unclear though.
It would be better if OP would clarify the etymology of their original idioma, to get any worthfull help.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Actually, yes it is a curse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Glosbe.com](https://glosbe.com/tr/en/k%C3%B6r%20olas%C4%B1.) *kör olası* enjoys a broad semantic field, but the most popular seems to be:

> blooming

For a specific application to *eye*, I might have chosen *[lousy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lousy)*, because it's dual meaning suggests disfunction as well as irritation and contempt:

> adjective (lousier, lousiest)
>
> 1.0 informal Very poor or bad:
>   *the service is usually lousy*
>
> 1.1 Used to express anger, contempt, or annoyance:
>
> *ODO*

Comment: “I jabbed a finger at his lousy eye”? That just sounds he has one good eye and one wonky one… sounds rather strange in this context.

Comment: Blooming isn't a typical adjective in AmE for this meaning.

Comment: Thank you for your time! The word *kör* means blind, and *olası* means "to be" or "may it be". The two words together usually apply specifically for the eye...so "blooming" is kind of broader. Also,it is kind of like a curse so I wouldn't really say "lousy" (because it's like you're telling the person that you want him/her to be blind). I thought there would be an exact equivalent term in English (applying specifically to the eye). From your answer (and the above comments), I see that there probably isn't any. Anyways, thanks for your time :).